# How do two foreach function work if 1 foreach is inside the other

Tags: php, foreach

I cant understand the logic of how two foreach functions work together if one of them is inside the other, for example this:

```
foreach ($projects as $project){
    foreach ($users as $user){

    }
}
```

when the first foreach gets a project, then foreach of all users goes thru all users till it has none and then returns back and repeat? or when it finds the first user too?

This might seem like a pretty basic question but I am not being able to find it somewhere else.

Comment: If you don't understand - add debugging with `echo` for example, and see what happens.

Comment: Think of a 2 dimensional matrix (a plain grid).

Comment: In PHP 5, when foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. [...] In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

Comment: Each iteration of the outer foreach loop executes the inner foreach loop and in turn each iteration of the inner foreach loop executes the body of the inner foreach loop (in your example the body of the inner loop is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this by yourself, its quite simple. Just write two dummy-arrays and iterate over them with two loops. Below is an example.

1. It will find a project.
2. The inner foreach user-loop will be executed for each user object found
3. It will find the next project
4. It will again run the inner foreach-loop for the project.

What I want to say with that:

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    "element1" => "value1",
    "element2" => "value2",
    "element3" => "value3"
);

$array2 = array(
    "element1.1" => "value1.1",
    "element2.1" => "value2.1",
    "element3.1" => "value3.1"
);

foreach($array1 as $arr1) {
    print_r($arr1);
    echo "<br>";

    foreach($array2 as $arr2) {
        print_r($arr2);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
value1
value1.1
value2.1
value3.1
value2
value1.1
value2.1
value3.1
value3
value1.1
value2.1
value3.1
```

Comment: how can I break it? in this case there are 3 values, but what if there are 5000 values? I dont want it to go thru all of them if I find the result I want in the 2nd. is there somekind of a break function/code or `return value` stops it?

Comment: You can use `break;` ... but honestly, I'm not too sure if thats the right approach for you. May you wanna explain what you're trying to do? Are you trying to itterate over two SQL query results?

Comment: Im using laravel and Im trying to find user wage for every user who works for every exact project. I've set relations up and everything, but just couldnt figure out how 2 or more foreach inside each other work. but thanks a lot!

Comment: If the data is stored in database and you have some foreign key relations, you should really learn something about `SQL Join` - it allows you to join up two tables together, so you'll only have one result set. That leads to only one foreach loop and it will reduce the loading time of your website.